# What's the meaning of these notations in the cost fuction?

Tags: regression, gradient-descent, notation

Except for the summation, I'm having a hard time figuring out the meaning of these notations. As I assume this is generic and the context is not that necessary, I'm here asking for help. (also, is just the cost function for a linear regression, don't think this will be a problem). What's the meaning of the two vertical bars? And ˆw? And the upsidedown triangle?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the common usages:

- The two vertical bars around a *vector* $||\mathbf x||$ means "the norm of $\mathbf x$". Normally, one would write $||\mathbf x||_p$ to denote that it is Lp-norm but, typically it is L2-norm and the subscript is dropped.
- Upside down triangle is the *gradient*, i.e. derivative. Normally, a subscript indicating with variable to differentiate would be present. For example, $\nabla_{\mathbf w}L=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf w}$.
- $\hat {\mathbf w}$ means the *estimated* value of $\mathbf w$. Hat is commonly used for denoting estimated values of parameters.

Comment: What about the arrow in the cost function? Is that still the norm of e?

Comment: I don't see any arrow. Are you asking $\hat \epsilon$?

Comment: Yes. I mean, in the first line of my print, it doesn't look like || ||, but it looks like a two vertical bars, one arrow and another vertical bar

Comment: I see, it's just bad notation. The hat seems to slip towards right a bit. So, it's not arrow.